# JQuery hide the first 3 div elements

Tags: jquery, html

I have several divs with 'resultblock' class. All I want is to show the first 3 divs and hide the others with jquery. But the code below does not work. Could you please help me to find my mistake.

```
//pushing all the divs into array
var results_list = [];
$('.resultblock').each(function () {
    results_list.push(this);
});

//hide all the divs
$('.resultblock').each(function () {
    $(this).hide();
});

//show the first 3 divs
var i;
for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    $(results_list[i]).show();
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`:gt`](https://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) selector

> Select all elements at an index greater than index within the matched set.
>
> **index**: Zero-based index

```
$('.resultblock:gt(2)').hide();
```